# How can I find out which Javascript function was invoked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I have a button or anything else in a webpage what I can click on.
When I click on it, a JQuery function will be invoked.

I use Google Chrome 44.
In Chrome DevTools how can I find out which Javascript function was invoked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try defining event handler as named function , log `event.handleObj.handler` to `console` . See also `Elements` -> `Event Listeners` `console`

```js
function doStuff(e) {
  console.log(e, e.handleObj.handler)
}

$("button").on("click", doStuff);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<button>click</button>
```